# Returning multiple values to a dataframe from a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
def makeaddr(a,b,c,d):
    return ipaddress.IPv4Address(bytes([a,b,c,d]))

def ipaddr():
    for x in range(256):
        a = makeaddr(x,x,x,x)
        a = str(a)
        return a

data = {'Ipaddress':[ipaddr() for x in range(256)]}
df = pd.DataFrame({key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in data.items() })
print(df)
```

How can I return the ipaddress from my code from 0.0.0.0 to x.x.x.x into the dictionary so that my dataframe can print the ipaddress.

---

I am planning to make a dataframe which will give me the output of

- IPAddress
- Domain Name
- Lat&Long
- Country

---

I would like my program to print out all the IP address from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 but in order to do that I would need to have the ipaddr()
to return multiple values is there a way to do it?

---

---

I Found a solution to my problem it is given below :-

```
import pandas as pd
import ipaddress
import socket
import geocoder
import threading
import csv
list1= []
list2= []
list3= []
list4= []

def makeaddr(a,b,c,d):
    return ipaddress.IPv4Address(bytes([a,b,c,d]))

def ip():
    for x in range(256):
        try:
            a = makeaddr(0,0,0,x)
            b = makeaddr(0,0,0,x)
            b = str(b)
            hostb = socket.gethostbyaddr(str(b))
            hostname = hostb[0]
            g = geocoder.ip(b)
            g1 = g.latlng
            g2 = g.city
            list1.append(a)
            list2.append(hostname)
            list3.append(g1)
            list4.append(g2)
        except:
            list1.append(a)

def ip1():
    for x in range(256):
        try:
            a = makeaddr(0,0,x,255)
            b = makeaddr(0,0,x,255)
            b = str(b)
            hostb = socket.gethostbyaddr(str(b))
            hostname = hostb[0]
            g = geocoder.ip(b)
            g1 = g.latlng
            g2 = g.city
            list1.append(a)
            list2.append(hostname)
            list3.append(g1)
            list4.append(g2)
        except:
            list1.append(a)

def ip2():
    for x in range(256):
        try:
            a = makeaddr(0,x,255,255)
            b = makeaddr(0,x,255,255)
            b = str(b)
            hostb = socket.gethostbyaddr(str(b))
            hostname = hostb[0]
            g = geocoder.ip(b)
            g1 = g.latlng
            g2 = g.city
            list1.append(a)
            list2.append(hostname)
            list3.append(g1)
            list4.append(g2)
        except:
            list1.append(a)
def ip3():
    for x in range(256):
        try:
            a = makeaddr(x,255,255,255)
            b = makeaddr(x,255,255,255)
            b = str(b)
            c = 'Host Not Found'
            hostb = socket.gethostbyaddr(str(b))
            hostname = hostb[0]
            g = geocoder.ip(b)
            g1 = g.latlng
            g2 = g.city
            list1.append(a)
            list2.append(hostname)
            list3.append(g1)
            list4.append(g2)
        except:
            list1.append(a)

threads = []
t1 = threading.Thread(target=ip(),args=())
t2 = threading.Thread(target=ip1(),args=())
t3 = threading.Thread(target=ip2(),args=())
t4 = threading.Thread(target=ip3(),args=())
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
data = {'IP':list1,'L&L':list3,'City':list4,'DN':list2}
df = pd.DataFrame({key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in data.items() })  #using a dict
print(df)
df.to_csv('csv12345.csv', sep ='\t')
```

**If anyone can reduce the LOC or improve this code feel free to do it.**

Comment: The Solution to my program can be done by creating an empty list and appending it from the for loop and then printing the data frame I was able to add Ipaddress,Lat&Long,City and Domain Name

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import ipaddress

def makeaddr(ip):
    return ipaddress.IPv4Address(bytes(ip))
```

I would make some changes to your `ipaddr()` function because, at the moment, it returns a scalar rather than a list.

```
def ipaddr():
    four_random_ints = [random.randint(0, 256) for x in range(4)]
    address = makeaddr(four_random_ints)
    return address

names = ['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky']

data = {'Names': names,
        'IP address':[ipaddr() for name in names]}
```

Output

```
{'Names': ['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],
 'IP address': [IPv4Address('43.70.58.224'),
  IPv4Address('71.142.187.150'),
  IPv4Address('39.224.203.109'),
  IPv4Address('96.242.248.198')]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output

```
    Names   IP address
0   Tom     43.70.58.224
1   Jack    71.142.187.150
2   Steve   39.224.203.109
3   Ricky   96.242.248.198
```

Comment: But what if I wanted to print it for x.x.x.x it should go from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255..255.255 is that possible?

Comment: I found a solution

Comment: What I did was use a list and stored all the outputs from the for loop in it I will edit my answer to show the solution thanks for your help much appreciated